# How to send text which contains custom emoji via TelegramBot?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot, emoji

How to send text which contains custom emoji via TelegramBot (Javascript and TelegramBot library) ?

[image]

When I copy a custom emoji as text, it is displayed in the old style instead.

I want this done in javascript like below

```
import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api'

export const bot = new TelegramBot(token, 
    { 
        polling: true
    })

bot.sendMessage(...)
...
```

Anybody can help me?